# Android set Imageview src dynamicly into a listview

Tags: android, mysql, listview, android-listview

I am working on a android project where I should list data from a mysql database and set an image's src when it is inside a `ListView`, the name off the image is taken from the drawable resources. Here's the code for designing the `ListView`, the `TAG_DRAP` in the database is show like this `@drawable/equip1`:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

// dismiss the dialog after getting all products
    pDialog.dismiss();
    // updating UI from Background Thread
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    AllProductsActivity.this, productsList,
                    R.layout.list_item_equipes, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                            TAG_NAME,TAG_DRAP,TAG_DRAP},
                    new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name,R.id.surname,R.id.icon });


            //getResources().getIdentifier("TAG_DRAP", "drawable", context.getPackageName())
            // updating listview

            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to create and use a custom list adapter in your project.
in your custom list adapter you can dynamically get your image-view from each list-item and set what ever you want to it.

here is and example:

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Item> items) {
     super(context, resource, items);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

View v = convertView;

if (v == null) {

    LayoutInflater vi;
    vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.itemlistrow, null);

}

Item p = getItem(position);

if (p != null) {

    TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.id);
    TextView tt1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.categoryId);
    TextView tt3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.description);

    if (tt != null) {
        tt.setText(p.getId());
    }
    if (tt1 != null) {

        tt1.setText(p.getCategory().getId());
    }
    if (tt3 != null) {

        tt3.setText(p.getDescription());
    }
}

return v;
```

}

and here is the link : [list-adapter custom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view)